# PHP / Prado property 'treatment'

Tags: php, oop, prado

I'm learning Prado php framework for a while now, and I've been wondering about one feature, if it's from PHP or somehow implemented in Prado.

Namely, classes used in Prado can utilize properties (fields) that aren't declared in the class itself, but 'defined' by set and get methods.

Here's an example:

```
class myClass extends somePradoClass {

    public function myPradoMethod() {
        $MyVariable = 22;
        echo $MyOtherVariable; // this one is read only (only get method defined)
    }

    public function getMyVariable() {
        return 0;
    } 

    public function setMyVariable($value) {
        $this->isFieldFromParentClass = $value;
    }

    public function getMyOtherVariable() {
        return $this->isOtherFieldFromParentClass;
    }

}
```

Now, somehow it is perfectly fine to use $MyVariable and $MyOtherVariable throughout the class, as if they were declared as class properties.

So, question again: **is this a PHP or Prado feature?**

Thx

Comment: sound weird to me, I don't think it works at lest not the way your think.

Comment: agreed :), i'm puzzled too... but it somehow works and i'm wondering HOW :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is neither a PHP feature nor a Prado feature.
I don't know Prado, but PHP has not such feature, so Prado can't have it either ;)

What you are looking for however, are things such as this: `$this->myUndefinedMember = $something`

Your example uses **local variables**, these **cannot** be set and read from automagically.

This will invoke the magic `__set` method, if defined that is.

Prado could (I don't know if it does) define this method for a certain superclass that you usually use and then dynamically check whether a setter method has been defined for that variable name.

The signature is as follows:

```
public function __set($name, $value)
```

The maigc method `__get($name)` works analogously.

If you do not set it as public, you will only be able to use this property-like feature from within the class( or subclasses).

As a reference, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) on PHP5's feature or overloading properties and methods.

## Update

A sample implementation could look like this:

```
class MyMagicSuperClass{
    public function __get($name){
        $getter_name = 'get'.ucwords($name);
        if(method_exists($this, $getter_name){
            return $this->$getter_name();
        }

        //error handling
    }

    public function __set($name, $value){
        $setter_name = 'get'.ucwords($name);
        if(method_exists($this, $setter_name){
            return $this->$setter_name($value);
        }

        //error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the methods in OP's code I think magic method in question is `__call()`. Local variables **never** invoke `__get()` or `__set()`, they are different from class properties.

Comment: Have a look at the first three paragraphs :) (I edited the third in to make things more clearly immediately after, so you may hav emissed that) - However, `__call()` wouldn't get invoked, since he never actually invokes something explicitely.

Comment: thx for your answers guys. I also like the sample implementation. PHP is a wild language :)

Comment: hehe you're welcome, I've aso heard that PHP is "consistently inconsistent, and after reading this nice (german) article, I'd would agree hehe http://blog.benny-baumann.de/?p=334

Answer (score 1):

I answer very late to this but I felt the answers posed very confusing to a simple feature.

To give a much simpler answer. Any Prado classes that inherits from TComponent use the __set and __get functions.

More about php magic functions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

So if u have a function that starts with "get" or "set" they will be called when use the rest of the function name as fields.

This is the actual prado code for __get the __set is about the same

```
    public function __get($name)
{
    $getter='get'.$name; $jsgetter = 'getjs'.$name;
    if(method_exists($this,$getter))
    {
        // getting a property
        return $this->$getter();
    }
    else if(method_exists($this,$jsgetter))
    {
        // getting a property
        return (string)$this->$jsgetter();
    }
    else if(strncasecmp($name,'on',2)===0 && method_exists($this,$name))
    {
        // getting an event (handler list)
        $name=strtolower($name);
        if(!isset($this->_e[$name]))
            $this->_e[$name]=new TList;
        return $this->_e[$name];
    }
    else
    {
        throw new TInvalidOperationException('component_property_undefined',get_class($this),$name);
    }
}
```